# Threading in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

i have program like this

```
private void  do_my_method_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
      //there are some variables and methods here

      //works fine
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Start_method);  

      // when added gives error this thread owned by other thread
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Start_method_2);
}

Start_method(object state)
{
}

Start_method_2(object state)
{
}
```

output of  `Start_method` is used in `Start_method_2`        i dont know exactly where i am going wrong and i am a newbie for WPF and C#.

Comment: "gives error this thread owned by other thread" Please check this, post the _exact_ error message (not in a comment)

Comment: Common guys, take it easy on him, he said he was new. Give him some constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tudor suggested, inside `Start_method_2` you are modifying the GUI I think.

Use `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` if you are modifying something on the UI which works on the main thread. Here is an example:

```
var sync = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

sync.Post(x => { 

    TextBlock1.Text = "Foo";

}, null);
```

This code is safe but it misses a lot (exception handling, etc.). Here is also another question for a similar issue which I suffered when I knew about threading a little:

[Simple Async operation with Continuation scenario doesn't work on a WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423086/simple-async-operation-with-continuation-scenario-doesnt-work-on-a-wpf-app)

Answer (score 0):

If the output of method 1 is used in the second you are in danger of a race condition.

The exception is probably caused by accessing a UI control in the worker. Show us the methods so we can give more detailed solutions.